# Copy file to local machine *after* Enter-PSSession

Tags: powershell

I know that I can use `Copy-Item` with `-ToSession` or `-FromSession` to transfer a file using WinRM.
But my Use-Case is, that I have already used `Enter-PSSession REMOTEPC` to work on another PC and now (inside of this session) I want to copy a file from the REMOTEPC back to my local PC using WinRM. Is this possible with `-ToSession` ? And what would I have to specify as argument?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The session must initially have been created with `New-PSSession -ComputerName`. Using just `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName` is not sufficient in this use-case!

I haven't found a perfect answer yet, but here are some insights and a decent workaround: It is possible to leave a session with `exit` an re-enter it *without providing credentials* even if it wasn't assigned to a variable (the examples assume that only one PSSession-instance exists):

`Get-PSSession | Enter-PSSession`

You can even assign the session to a variable subsequently:

`$remoteSession = Get-PSSession`

Now you can use `$remoteSession` as argument for `-ToSession` or `-FromSession`. And when you are finished copying files use `Enter-PSSession $remoteSession`, if necessary. All without the need to re-type the credentials.